# Is there a tidy way to create 'internal' properties in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, structure

In JavaScript, I may begin writing a 'library' or collection of functionality using a top level object like this:

```
window.Lib = (function()
{
    return {

        // Define Lib here.
        //

    };

})();
```

I may also add some functions within `Lib` which serve to create objects related to it:

```
window.Lib = (function()
{
    return {

        ObjectA: function()
        {
            var _a = 5;

            return {

                getA: function(){ return _a; }

            };

        },


        ObjectB: function()
        {
            var _b = 2;
            var _c = 1;

            return {

                getB: function(){ return _b; }

            };

        }

    };

})();
```

Which would be used like so:

```
var thing = Lib.ObjectA();
var thing2 = Lib.ObjectA();
var thing3 = Lib.ObjectB();
```

And I can use the methods within each of those created above to get the values of `_a` defined within `ObjectA()` or `_b` defined within `ObjectB()`:

```
alert(thing.getA()); // 5
alert(thing3.getB()); // 2
```

What I want to achieve is this:

Say I want to access the property `_c` (defined within `ObjectB()`) but **only within the scope of `Lib`**. How could I go about that? By this I mean, I want to make the property readable within any function that I define within the object returned by `Lib()`, but I don't want to expose those values outside of that.

Code example:

```
window.Lib = (function()
{
    return {

        ObjectA: function(){ ... },
        ObjectB: function(){ ... },

        assess: function(obj)
        {
            // Somehow get _c here.
            alert( obj.getInternalC() );
        }

    };

})();
```

Which would work like so:

```
var thing = Lib.ObjectB();
alert( thing.getInternalC() ) // error | null | no method named .getInternalC()

Lib.assess(thing); // 1
```

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: I've added an example to my answer of how you can *almost* do this.

Comment: Would John's "makeClass" function be of use here for the instance? http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-class-instantiation/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want per-instance protected properties? That is, properties on the instances created by `ObjectA`, `ObjectB`, etc., but which are **only** accessible to the code within your library, and not to code outside it?

You cannot currently do that *properly* in JavaScript, but you'll be able to in the next version using [private name objects](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony%3aprivate_name_objects). (See "Almost doing it" below for something similar you can do now in ES5, though.)

It's easy to create data that's shared by all code within `Lib`, but not *per-instance* properties, like so:

```
window.Lib = (function()
{
    var sharedData;

    // ...
})();
```

All of the functions defined within there (your `ObjectA`, etc.) will have access to that one `sharedData` variable, which is completely inaccessible from outside. But it's not per-instance, each object created by `ObjectA`, `ObjectB`, etc. doesn't get its own copy.

#### Almost doing it

If your code will be running in an environment with ES5 (so, any modern browser, where "modern" does *not* include IE8 or earlier), you can have *obscured* but not actually private properties, via `Object.defineProperty`. This is similar to how private name objects will work in ES.next, but not *genuinely* private:

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/idapak/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/idapak/1/edit)

```
window.Lib = (function() {
    // Get a random name for our "c" property
    var c = "__c" + Math.round(Math.random() * 1000000);

    // Return our library functions
    return {

        ObjectA: function() {
            // Create an object with a couple of public proprties:
            var obj = {
                pub1: "I'm a public property",
                pub2: "So am I"
            };

            // Add our obscured "c" property to it, make sure it's
            // non-enumerable (doesn't show up in for-in loops)
            Object.defineProperty(obj, c, {
                enumerable: false,  // false is actually the default value, just emphasizing
                writable:   true,
                value:      "I'm an obscured property"
            });

            // Return it
            return obj;
        },

        ObjectB: function(){ /* ... */ },

        assess: function(obj) {
            // Here, we access the property using the `c` variable, which
            // contains the property name. In JavaScript, you can access
            // properties either using dotted notation and a literal
            // (`foo.propName`), or using bracketed notation and a string
            // (`foo["propName"]`). Here we're using bracketed notation,
            // and our `c` string, which has the actual property name.
            display( obj[c] );
        },


        alter: function(obj, value) {
            // Similarly, we can change the value with code that has
            // access to the `c` variable
            obj[c] = value;
        }
    };
})();
```

And use it like this:

```
// Create our object
var o = Lib.ObjectA();

// Play with it
display("pub1: " + o.pub1); // displays "pub1: I'm a public property"
display("c: " + o.c);       // displays "c: undefined" since `o` has no property called `c`
Lib.assess(o);              // displays "I'm an obscured property"

// Note that our obscured property doesn't show up in for-in loops or Object.keys:
var propName, propNames = [];
for (propName in o) {
    propNames.push(propName);
}
display("propNames: " + propNames.join(","));
display("Object.keys: " + Object.keys(o).join(","));

// Our Lib code can modify the property
Lib.alter(o, "Updated obscured property");
Lib.assess(o);
```

The object returned by `Lib.ObjectA` has a property whose name will change every time `Lib` is loaded, and which is not enumerable (doesn't show up in `for-in` loops). The only way to get at it is to know it's name (which, again, changes every time `Lib` is created — e.g., every page load). The code within `Lib` knows what the property name is, because it's in the `c` variable which is shared by all of the `Lib` code. Since you can access properties using bracketed notation and a string, we can use `instance[c]` to access the property.

You see how these are pretty well obscured. Code outside of `Lib` don't see the obscured property when enumerating the property in the object, and they don't know the semi-random name we assigned it, so can't find the property. Of course, you could find it via inspection using a debugger, but debuggers can do lots of things.

And in fact, this is how private properties will work in ES.next, except that `c` won't be a string, it'll be a private name object.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you would "just" need to *declare* those variables within the *Context* of `Lib`

```
window.Lib = (function()
{
    var _c = 42;   

    return {
    };
});
```

Notice that I removed the *automatic invocation* of that *pseudo constructor function*. That means, you would need to create multiple calls to `Lib()` for multiple instances, each would have its own *unique* set of values.

```
var inst1 = Lib(),
    inst2 = Lib();
```

If you only want to have *shared access* from all child-context's (functions), you can just use the same pattern you already do (only with moving the *var* declarations to the parent context like shown above).

Comment: But that's not per-instance. The OP clearly wants *per-instance* protected properties.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: I thought I captured that. -- Well, I only captured it very "globally" by re-calling the whole constructor thing. So yea, might be not the real deal.

Comment: @ jAndy: No, look again at the OP's question and in particular at the code. The goal is for `Lib` to be created *once*, and to have `ObjectA`, `ObjectB`, etc., create instances of objects, but to have all of the code within `Lib` be able to access properties on those instances that cannot be accessed from the outside world.